# Transforming a flattened list into a nested list of length 3

Tags: haskell

Given a flattened list in Haskell:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

and `n=3`

how can I change the list to:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

preferably a solution where `n` is a variable

Comment: What if n isn't divisible by 3?

Comment: You can assume that the list's size is always divisible by n

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good example show how to use of unfoldr as:

```
f n = unfoldr (\xs->if null xs then Nothing else Just (take n xs, drop n xs))
```

Note that it can accept infinite list as:

```
take 4 $ f 3 [1..]
```

gives

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

for characters

```
take 4 $ f 3 ['a'..]
```

gives

```
["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
```